# Setting up python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am still new to python and really need some help understanding an issue i am facing.

I have supposedly installed python3 successfully and i have ran a couple of projects with python but my problem is there are 3 different python paths on my machine and i dont know which one i am using.

i first did this:
`which -a python3`

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

/usr/local/bin/python3

/usr/bin/python3
```

Then i cd into each one of these files and did this `ls -ld python3`

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  9 26 Jan  2020 python3 -> python3.8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 *******  admin  40 24 Mar 09:22 python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_2/bin/python3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  31488 22 Sep  2020 python3
```

Can someone explain to me what these mean and also why are they not pointing to the same file?

here is my `~/.bash_profile`

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave

alias python=python3

# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"

export ANDROID_SDK=/Users/*****/Library/Android/sdk

export PATH=/Users/*******/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs

export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

***I am using a Mac with macOS Catalina as my operating system and bash as my shell.***

Comment: I think it usually means you have multiple installation of python3 from multiple sources such as from Brew, binary release, etc. and their folder containing their own executable `python3` are saved in different locations

Comment: It's clear from the paths that you are on macOS, but going forward, mentioning your platform and how exactly you installed Python would be good details to include in any question of this type.

Comment: If you are on Zsh, the contents of your `.bash_profile` won't matter at all. Perhaps also indicate which shell you are using (`echo "$SHELL"`)

Comment: @tripleee what do you mean by on Zsh?

Comment: There are multiple shells you can use; Bash used to be the default but since Catalina the default for new users is a different shell called Zsh. If you have Bash it will have offered to migrate you to use Zsh instead so you should definitely be able to remember whether you said yes or no when it asked you this. If you are not using Bash then its startup file is just ignored deadweight (though of course if you explicitly start up Bash at any point, those files will be used).

Comment: @tripleee i ran `echo $SHELL` in my terminal and got `/bin/bash`

Comment: Then all is good, in terms of understanding where we are and whether the information in your question is actually relevant. It would still be nice to [edit] it so it's complete.

Comment: @tripleee updated my bash_profile and added my OS and shell inside the quesiton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a system-installed `python3` (probably 3.8.2 if you are on Big Sur) in `/usr/bin/python3` and a Homebrew-installed one in `/usr/local/bin/python3` which is a symlink to the real location where `brew` installed it.  This is all quite normal, though if the system-installed Python 3 was sufficient for your needs, installing another copy with Homebrew was redundant as such.  But this is all quite normal; your system needs a particular version to exist, and you should not touch that, but you are free to install a non-system version in parallel and use that for your personal needs if you want to.

You can use the explicit paths to run any particular version (try `/usr/bin/python3 --version` and `/usr/local/bin/python3 --version`) but usually you don't want or need to. Out of the box, your `PATH` is ordered so that `/usr/local/bin` takes precedence over `/usr/bin`, so that locally installed versions shadow the system default versions in regular use.

As an aside, you have the Visual Studio Code path added twice, and you don't need to `export PATH` multiple times (or actually at all, as the system startup files will already have marked this variable for `export`).

Comment: Hi, thank you for getting back to me. I am actually using macOS Catalina not Big Sur. That is true i have downloaded python a while ago from the python website then i read a couple of comments that suggested i install using brew since when a update occurs brew updates it automatically. when i run `/usr/local/bin/python3 --version` i get `Python 3.9.2` and when i run `/usr/bin/python3 --version` i get `Python 3.7.3`. what about this path `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3` does it take precendence over the others? also when i get its python version its `3.8.1`

Comment: Yes, according to the `which` output (but we don't know if we can trust that without more information about which shell you are using). Just `python3 --version` should corroborate this.

Comment: when i did `python3 --version` i got `Python 3.8.1`. so based on `which -a python3` this means i am using `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3` over `/usr/local/bin/python3` is that the right way of working with python?

Comment: is this python `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3` the one installed from the python website?

Comment: Without more information about what exactly you did, we can only speculate. If this was something you did recently, this is not the version Python.org would have offered you. The stanza in your `.bash_profile` which selects this version looks like it came from Homebrew, vaguely.

Comment: I honestly cant remember, i installed python a year ago but cant remember how i installed it then again a couple of months ago using homebrew. Do you recommend that i uninstall all 3 pythons i currently have then install them again?

Comment: I can see no reason to do that.

Comment: last question, should i be using this `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3` or this `/usr/local/bin/python3` & which `PATH` in my `bash_profile` should i remove?

Comment: Whichever makes sense for your use case. For new development targeting new installations of Python, using the newer version makes sense; but if you are developing for a user base or platform where you need to support 3.8, using that makes more sense. If you can't decide one way or the other, probably use the newer version for now, since you are less likely to bump into problems when you find something online and try it out.

Comment: How do i change the precedence of which one i am using?

Comment: Removing the `PATH` hack from your `.bash_profile` would expose the version in `/usr/local/bin` as your default. You will need to log out and back in for the change to take (though you can separately hack the variable in your interactive shell if you prefer; `echo PATH=${PATH#*:}` should display something vaguely useful which you can execute if it looks correct by simply removing the `echo`

Comment: (We can't see your full `PATH` so it's possible that it contains other chaff too. There are certainly other ways to arrange this, too, but perhaps ask a new question on a different site if you need the full spiel.)

Comment: removing this from my bash_profile 
 `PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH` ?

Comment: here is my full path `PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin`

Comment: Yes, remove that from `.bash_profile` and at the shell prompt `PATH=${PATH#*:}` or more verbosely `PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"` (the latter also removes the duplicate from the end of the `PATH`)

Comment: in my bash_profile here `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.8` should i specify python3 or 3.8 or 3.9?

Comment: Probably whichever one you prefer. I don't use Virtualenvwrapper myself so I don't remember exactly what this setting does.

Comment: Do you mind me asking which one do you use?

Comment: I use different Python versions for different projects. Some stuff I work on needs to be compatible back to 3.6. I use `pyenv` to keep multiple versions available but don't particularly like its overall model so I create a new local `virtualenv` manually for each version for each project that needs to be tested on multiple versions.